# Converting Linked Binary Tree to Array-based Binary Tree

Tags: arrays, data-structures, binary-tree

How can I convert a binary tree which is initially implemented as a linked structure to an array based?

There would be no problem if the binary tree is something like a complete binary tree like this:

```
      5
     / \
    /   \
   /     \ 
  3       7
 / \     / \
1   4   6   9
```

since I could just use a breadth first traversal in adding its nodes consecutively in the array.

But what if it's an incomplete tree like these:

```
      5
     / \
    /   \
   /     \ 
  3       7
   \     / \
    4   6   9

      5
       \
        \
         \ 
          7
         / \
        6   9

       5
      / \
     /   \
    /     \ 
   3       7
    \  
     4
```

There are nodes that doesn't have any children or its children count is not exactly 2. How can I convert this to an array?

How can I add the incomplete binary tree examples in an array in this way:

```
1st: 5 3 7 null 4 6 9
2nd: 5 null 7 null null 6 9
3rd: 5 3 7 null 4 null null
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing this we can use level order traversal of binary tree with some modification.

Normally in level order traversal we add only those tree nodes which are not null in order to avoid infinite looping . But in this case since you want to print element of all levels until a level does not contain even a single non null node.

In order to achieve this we can maintain a `count` variable which keeps track of how many non null nodes are present in queue, and `count` is decremented in case when a non null node is popped from queue.Also in queue we have to add both left and right node irrespective of whether parent node is null or non null.

If parent node popped out is null then handle it separately by adding its left and right children as null in queue(if part) else if parent node is not null decrement the count and add its left and right child , also increment `count` based on number of non null nodes from left and right node.(else part)

Also, along with `count` we have to maintain how many nodes are there at particular level. We are using this because if count at partiular level becomes 0, then to we have to print all remaining nodes at that level (which are null). So, we need to know how many nodes are can still be present at that level.

This, can be explained from your Example 3. In this at level 3 (if root level is at level 1) , when we reach to node with value 4 our count will become 0 and we will come out of the loop without printing remaining node value at that level which are (null, null). In order to keep track of how many nodes are present at each level we are using variables `levelnode` and `currlevelnode`.

Here is the working example of the same :

```
    private static List<String> levelorderTraversal(Node root) {
            Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
            queue.add(root);
            Node node;
            int count=1;
            int levelnode=1, currlevelnode=0;
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(count>0) {  //count represents number of non null nodes in queue
                node = queue.poll();
                if(levelnode == 0) { //if we have reached to next level
                   levelnode=currlevelnode;
                   currlevelnode = 0;
                }
                if(node==null) { //if parent node is null
                    result.add(null);
                    queue.add(null); //add its left child as null
                    queue.add(null); //add its right child as null
                } else {
                    count--;  //since we have popped out non null node decrement count
                    result.add(Integer.toString(node.val));
                    if(node.left != null) { //increment count if any of the left / right child is non null
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(node.right != null) { 
                        count++;
                    }
                    queue.add(node.left); //add left child of parent node
                    queue.add(node.right); // add right child of parent node
                }
                currlevelnode+=2;
                levelnode--;
            }
            while(levelnode>0) { //if at last level still nodes are left to be added
               result.add(null);
               levelnode--;
            }
            return result;
   }
```

Comment: @robert If you have any issues related to the solution please let me know.